# Modification to new List is duplicated in original list

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a list, and in my method I'm trying to return a new list with modifications.

The problem though is that the changes I make to the Id's of the list of clues are also being made to the list of clues I'm passing in.

```
        public List<Clue> NewOrderList(List<Clue> clues, int[] ids)
    {
        var newClueOrder = new List<Clue>();

        // For each ID in the given order
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get the original clue that matches the given ID
            var clue = clues.First(clue1 => clue1.Id == ids[i]);

            // Add the clue to the new list. 
            newClueOrder.Add(clue);

            // Retain the ID of the clue 
            newClueOrder[i].Id = clues[newClueOrder.Count - 1].Id;
        }

        return newClueOrder;
    }
```

Why is this, and what is the best solution for this? I've seen similar questions but to be honest I didn't quite understand what exactly the solution is.

Comment: Jon Skeet gives a real good discussion of this and why/when it happens here - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: a list is by reference. If you want a new object (clue) create a copy.

Comment: What and where is the best place to create a copy of it?

Comment: Only your list is new.  The clues are the same objects in both lists.

Comment: So what is the best way to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Clue` is a reference type.  You're not creating a new `Clue` instance, you're actually changing the existing instance.

To get around this, you'll want to use a copy constructor or some sort of cloning to get a deep copy:

```
        // Get the original clue that matches the given ID
        var clue = clues.First(clue1 => clue1.Id == ids[i]);

        // Copy constructor
        var newClue = new Clue(clue);

        // Or, use cloning
        var newClue = clue.Clone();

        // Add the clue to the new list. 
        newClueOrder.Add(newClue);

        // Retain the ID of the clue 
        newClueOrder[i].Id = clues[newClueOrder.Count - 1].Id;
```

In the `Clone()` or copy constructor, you'll need to make copies of all the other non-immutable reference types, don't just reassign the reference.  For example, assuming that Clue has :

```
public class Clue
{
    ...

    public Clue Clone()
    {
        Clue newClue = new Clue();
        newClue.SomeClassType = this.SomeClassType.Clone(); // You'll need to get a clone or copy of all non-immutable class members as well.
        newClue.Id = this.Id;  // Value types are copied by value, so are safe to assign directly.
        newClue.Name = this.Name;  //If Name is a string, then this is safe too, since they are immutable.
        return newClue;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when I'm adding the clue the newClueOrder list, do I add the newClue (your example shows the original clue being added)?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your example to clone the clue. Do I create a method Clone which returns a cloned clue. Does this method accept the clue as a parameter? In your example, you create a new clue and make copies of all the types... but you show the newClue referencing itself? Is that an error?

Comment: First comment - yes, that's what I meant.  I edited to correct.  Second comment - yes, you create a Clone() method on the Clue class.  The newClue doesn't reference itself.  The `this` qualifier refers to the existing instance you're using to create initialize/create the newClue instance with.

Answer (score 2):

You a creating a shallow copy. It sounds like you want a deep copy of the list. So, I would first create a deep copy and then modify whatever you need to modify and return the new list.

You can serialize and desirialize the list to create a deep copy

when you create a deep copy of the list you are creating new clue objects and not just referencing them like in a shallow copy

```
   public List<Clue> NewOrderList(List<Clue> clues)
   {
        List<Clue> newstringOrder = CreateDeepCopy(clues);

        // Add code to modify list

        return newstringOrder;
   }


public List<Clue> CreateDeepCopy(List<Clue> c)
{
     //Serialization    
     if(c == null)
            return null;
     BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     bf.Serialize(ms, c);

     //Deserialization              
     ms.Position = 0;        
     List<Clue> list = (List<Clue>)bf.Deserialize(ms);       

     return list;    

}
```

Comment: How and where do I create a deep copy and serialize/deserialize it?

Comment: You create a deep copy by serializing/desirializing the original list. when you desirialize the list what you have is a deep copy of the original one

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? I'm not sure if I've ever had to serialize or derserialize a list, I've no idea how to do that.

Comment: Just added code sample on how to serialize/desirialize a string[]. Just change from array to list

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, where exactly do I invoke the serialize and deserialize methods with reference to my original code snippet?

Comment: At the very beginning of your method. Once you have a brand new deep copy of the original you can apply the changes to the new clues.

Comment: To be honest I'm still a bit lost on implementing a method to serialize and deserialize it... do I have to serialize it, THEN deserialize it immediately after, or where do I deserialize it?

Comment: Your example also seems to apply to an array, will it be any different for a List item? If possible, could you show I would invoke the serialization and deserialization in terms of my original code snippet?

Comment: Code edited to show serializing a list and where you would invoke serialization/desirialization